# Nesting contexpr functions error

Tags: c++, constexpr

The follwing code doesn't compile with g++/clang++.

```
constexpr int bar(int v) {
    if (v > 0){
        return v * 2;
    }
    return 2;
}

constexpr int foo(const int v) {
    constexpr auto x =  bar(v); // error
    return v;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = foo(1);
    constexpr auto b = bar(1); // ok
}
```

The error message is: x must be initailized by a constant expression

But from the line (ok) you see that bar() is constexpr.

if I change the body of foo() to

```
constexpr int foo(const int v) {
    return bar(v);
}
```

its ok!

I don't get this clear, why the first form isn't possilble.
I used g++-6.2.1, g++-7.0.0 and clang++-3.9.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is this

```
constexpr int foo(const int v) {
    auto x =  bar(v);
    return v;
}
```

The keyword constexpr means two very slightly different things.  A constexpr variable *must* be evaluated at compile time, whereas a constexpr function must be possible to evaluate at compile time. There is nothing to prevent you from calling foo at runtime.  This means...

1. The argument v is not necessarily constexpr.
2. When bar is called with b the answer might not be constexpr.
3. The result of cannot be stored in a constexpr variable as it might not be constexpr.

If foo is called at compile time then x is not stored, it is a temporary variable within the compiler, so making it constexpr doesn't make any sense.

The constexpr'ness of x can only make sense if foo is evaluated at runtime, in which case it cannot be constexpr, which cases an error.

Comment: Thank you for this valueable explanation! Originally I wanted to instatiate a template function inside foo() with the (constexpr, I thought) result of bar(). So that seem not to be possible ...

Comment: Do you mean something like constexpr foo(int i){ return f<i>(i);}  ?

Comment: Close: constexpr int foo(const int v) {
    constexpr auto x =  bar(v);
    ttt<x>();
    return v;
}

Comment: Ok, would be possible. But in real code the return value of bar() is a struct {}